# Strange connections to my sql server as user

Tags: mysql

First of all I'm a complete newbie in webdev and server management. But I have still been able to host my own website on digitalocean with perseverance.

Only few people knows about the website its host and it runs a mysql server (using ubuntu 18.04)

I just noticed my website returns some errors and from the logs it says that the connection to mysql is 'lost'.

I can access the mysql database from my server directly and a service mysql status returns me a "warning: can't get client address: connection reset by peer".

I checked the logs in var/log/mysql/error.log and there I noticed several connection attempts (as users - all denied) from unknown IPs to me (some coming from foreign countries).

I wonder what this is, if this is some kind of bots and if it might be linked to the issue described above.

Many thanks !

Adding some logs, the last rows are a bit odd:

````
2019-05-31T14:42:42.958632Z 6253 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_1' (using password: NO)
2019-05-31T14:42:44.857416Z 6254 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_1' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T14:42:45.706070Z 6255 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_1' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T14:42:46.547308Z 6256 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_1' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T14:42:47.365311Z 6257 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_1' (using password: NO)
2019-05-31T14:59:40.377985Z 6258 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_2' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T17:12:18.293648Z 6259 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_3' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T17:45:12.817284Z 6260 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_3' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T18:16:34.523692Z 6261 [Note] Access denied for user 'ACS'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_3' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T18:48:37.406706Z 6262 [Note] Access denied for user 'adam'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_3' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T18:58:05.874774Z 6263 [Warning] IP address 'SOME IP I DONT KNOW' has been resolved to the host name 'SOME IP I DONT KNOW.netsystemsresearch.com', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
2019-05-31T18:58:15.879556Z 6263 [Note] Got timeout reading communication packets
2019-05-31T19:19:37.825888Z 6264 [Note] Access denied for user 'admin'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_3' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T19:50:31.502666Z 6265 [Note] Access denied for user 'ADMIN'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_3' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T20:22:00.495135Z 6266 [Note] Access denied for user 'admindb'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_3' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T20:35:51.521541Z 6189 [Note] Aborted connection 6189 to db: 'MY_WEBSITE' user: 'ME' host: 'MY_OWN_IP' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2019-05-31T20:52:38.734675Z 6267 [Note] Access denied for user 'Bankruptcy'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_3' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T21:23:01.961102Z 6269 [Note] Access denied for user 'BANKRUPTCY'@'SOME_UNKNOWN_IP_3' (using password: YES)
2019-05-31T21:26:54.236087Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-05-31T21:26:54.236146Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-05-31T21:26:54.236904Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2019-05-31T21:26:54.237779Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events```
````

Comment: The first think you need to do on this server is enable a firewall. If you are running a web application which talks to the MySQL database, and nothing else should legitimately be connecting to the MySQL database, you must not permit it to accept connections from the outside world.

Comment: Despite only a few people knowing about it, most servers on the public Internet are continuously probed by IP addresses all over the world in search of open connections and known vulnerabilities. A firewall (iptables) which only allows expected access is the first defense, but a new Linux install will often not include one. I think Digital Ocean has a network-level (rather than on your server) firewall you can enable, where you would allow access for HTTP/HTTPS on the website, but block access to MySQL port 3306 and possibly everything else besides HTTP/HTTPs, and SSH

Comment: 1) these log entries seem to indicate somebody trying to brute force your mysql. You really should not allow direct remote access to mysql. Setting such things up is outside of the remit of SO, since SO is about software development, not admin stuff. 2) whether your errors relate to the brute force attempts is impossible to say based on so little information.

Comment: I doubt that the errors you are seeing are the result of the patient tap-tap-tap of the robots who mean to do you harm. If your database and web server are running on the same machine, do nothing else before you disable tcp connections to your database entirely and use sockets instead.